# Stopping the timeupdate function during and after seeking

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

Im trying to create a videojs function with the following conditions

- Disable seeking on unwatched parts of the video
- Allow seeking on watched parts (rewind)
- Video resumes where the user has left of

So far everything is working good except for disabling the seeking of unwatched parts of the video.

What happens is, the first time the user forward seeks it successfully goes back to the current time. but when done a second time the forward seeking is enabled

Below is my code

```
var video = videojs('#my-video').ready(function(){
var player = this;

if(player.tagAttributes['data-completed'] == "true"){
    //if video is tagged as completed.  user has free control of the seekbar
}
else{
    //starts where user left off
    $.ajax({
        url: base + "site/get_currentTime",
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){ 
            player.currentTime(result.currentTime);
        },
        error: function(ts) { }
    });

    //returns the video to the time before seeking happened
    player.on("seeking", function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: base + "site/get_currentTime",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){ 
                //result.currentTime is the time saved in the database
                if (result.currentTime < player.currentTime()) {
                    player.currentTime(result.currentTime-1);
                }
            },
            error: function(ts) { }
        });
    });

    //save to database the current time of the video 
    player.on("timeupdate", function(event) {
        var seek_status = player.seeking();
        if(seek_status == false){
            $.ajax({
                url:player.tagAttributes['data-url'] + "/" + player.currentTime(),
                type:'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result){  
                },
                error: function(ts) { console.log(ts)}
            });
        }
    });

    //sets the video to completed
    player.on('ended', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:player.tagAttributes['data-url'],
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){  
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(ts) {  }
        });
    });
}
});
```

what i think happens is, the timeupdate event is still running even when the seeking event is happening. is there any workaround to prevent this from happening?